# What does 'Roosevelt punched the Porc' mean?

Tags: the-social-network

In the film The Social Network in the opening scene while discussing which club Mark should aim to join there's a line from Mark saying

> The Phoenix is the most diverse. The Fly
>   Club, Roosevelt punched the Porc.

What does this mean?  I understand that being punched BY the Porc is getting an invite to an audition, so what does it mean here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to go through the entire conversation.

> Mark: The Phoenix is the most diverse. The Fly  Club, Roosevelt
>   punched the Porc
>
> Erica: Which one?
>
> Mark: The Porcellian, the Porc, it’s the best  of the best
>
> Erica: Which Roosevelt?
>
> Mark: Theodore

The Porcellian Club is a "final club" at Harvard and is also known as the "Porc". Punch within final clubs refers to getting the invitation but it [also refers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_club#The_clubs) to attending events within an organization. [Theodore Roosevelt was a member](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porcellian_Club) of the Porcellian Club, so Mark is most likely referring to the fact that a notable person, the 26th President of the United States participated in the Porc.

> Roosevelt punched the Porc

Literally, Roosevelt was a member *and* participated in the Porc, where "punched" has two meanings

- Get the invitation
- Participate in events